# Exclude from file one the lines in common with file two and preserve line order

Tags: bash, shell

**one**

```
pl
a
ff
c
b
nn
```

**two**

```
b
a
z
k
c
d
```

I want to remove from the first file all lines that are also in the second (common lines). And I want to maintain the file_one lines order.

It's possible to work in a line by line check mode, something like:

```
while read line; do
  if ! grep $line two; then
    echo $line >> one_only
  fi
done < one
```

But it likely isn't the best option for a fast check.
An other way would be using "comm" command on the files previously sorted:

```
comm -1 -2 <(sort one) <(sort two) \
  | tr '\n' '\|' \
  | sed 's/|/\\|/g;s/\\|$/\n/' \
  > common_lines

grep -v "$(cat common_lines)" one
```

first command creates a "logical OR pattern":

```
a\|b\|c
```

which can be reuse with grep to exclude common lines from the "one" file. In this way the original order of "one" lines is preserved. And the result will be:

```
pl
ff
nn
```

Can you suggest any other idea to minimize compute time even more?

Real input files are much more populated and contain short names (software names):

```
blender
gimp
vim
emacs
mozilla-firefox
google-earth
```

and so on...

Comment: Always quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. If you ran your code through shellcheck as the bash tag you added instructs you to do it'd have told you about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the lines of `two` as patterns, with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```sh
grep -Fx -f two -v one
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} !($0 in a)' two one
```

Regarding the  `while read` loop in your question, please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)